# Dynamically inspecting filter to generate joins on SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables, `Foo` and `Bar`, linked by a 1-n relationship (1 `Foo` linked to *n* `Bar`). Using SqlAlchemy, I'd like to query some `Foo` using a client-provided generic filter:

```
def get_foos(foo_fltr):
    return session.query(Foo).filter(foo_fltr).all()

foos = get_foos(foo_fltr=(Foo.value == 42))
```

So far so good. Now I'd also like to allow the caller to filter on Bar, such as this:

```
def get_foos(foobar_fltr):
    return session.query(Foo).join(Bar).filter(foobar_fltr).all()

foos2 = get_foos(foobar_fltr=((Foo.value == 42) & (Bar.value == 13)))
```

The problem is that when filtering on `Bar`, you need to add `join(Bar)` to the query, so you need two methods or two parameters, which is cumbersome to implement and to use.

What I'd like to do, is to **dynamically inspect** the provided SQLAlchemy filter to see if it relates to `Bar`, and if so **add the join automatically**, such as this:

```
def get_foos(fltr):
    q = session.query(Foo)
    if filter_reference_class(fltr, Bar):
        q = q.join(Bar)
    return q.filter(fltr).all()

foos1 = get_foo(fltr=(Foo.value == 42)) # No join
foos2 = get_foo(fltr=(Foo.value == 42) & (Bar.value == 13)) # Join
```

That way, only one method / one parameter is needed. The join is added automatically if it is needed.

I'm using the `sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ClauseElement::get_children()` method to scan the clause tree using this code:

```
def inspect(fltr):
    for child in fltr.get_children():
        inspect(child)
    # How to test fltr here?
```

The tree leafs being `AnnotatedColumn` objects. But here I'm stuck: **how can I detect to which class refers the column object**? I can't see anything in the SqlAlchemy documentation to do that.

Comment: Thank you for avoiding a dangling preposition.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that you can get the parent mapper at `child._annotations["parentmapper"]`, so the declarative class is `child._annotations["parentmapper"].class_`.

A less fragile way would probably be to just join on the table of the column (`child.table`) directly instead, which should work just as well.

Comment: could you atleast give some concrete solution? This question got some point because we do not want to write more functions for different joins and filters.

Comment: @Roel Not sure why you think this is not a concrete solution. The question is, "how can I detect to which class refers the column object?", and the answer is, use `child.table`.

Comment: Whoops! My bad!